# SQLSTATE[23503]: Foreign key violation error when seeding in Heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I have php laravel website deployed on Heroku.
I have some foreign key constrained tables which have data generated by seeders.
Everything was fine in localhost.
But it didn't work on Heroku.
When I seeding my data on heroku, I got these errors:

```
In Connection.php line 671:

  SQLSTATE[23503]: Foreign key violation: 7 ERROR:  insert or update on table
   "cartlists" violates foreign key constraint "cartlists_cart_id_foreign"
  DETAIL:  Key (cart_id)=(1) is not present in table "carts". (SQL: insert in
  to "cartlists" ("pNum", "pNo", "pSize", "cart_id", "updated_at", "created_a
  t") values (1, 1114460-PRBL, L, 1, 2020-06-13 18:47:48, 2020-06-13 18:47:48
  ) returning "id")


In PDOStatement.php line 129:

  SQLSTATE[23503]: Foreign key violation: 7 ERROR:  insert or update on table
   "cartlists" violates foreign key constraint "cartlists_cart_id_foreign"
  DETAIL:  Key (cart_id)=(1) is not present in table "carts".


In PDOStatement.php line 127:

  SQLSTATE[23503]: Foreign key violation: 7 ERROR:  insert or update on table
   "cartlists" violates foreign key constraint "cartlists_cart_id_foreign"
  DETAIL:  Key (cart_id)=(1) is not present in table "carts".
```

Does anyone have the same problem like me?

Comment: how does your seeder for `cartlists` decide what `cart_id` to use, 1 in this case?

Comment: It turns out that I didn't have a user which has a foreign key with a cart. That is where the error from.

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect to database hosted at Heroku and verify if the table carts is really populated.

Possible way: Carts::all()

If returns a empty collection e because the table is empty and that is the reason of the error

Comment: It turns out that I didn't have a user  which has a foreign key with a cart.